# KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFilesAsync() takes very long time

Tags: windows-8

I'm looping through videos in the `awaitKnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFilesAsync()` method and first I thought something was wrong with my code, but on my machine with an SSD drive it takes some 5-20 seconds to get the files. The folder only contains 5 small files.

What is even stranger is that if I specify a subfolder with `await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFolderAsync("subfolder")` and then do `await folder.GetFilesAsync()` from that folder - it loops the files in a second!

I have the same symptoms in the PicturesLibrary. Is it just me? Maybe it's because the OS tries to load up "linked" video libraries from the network (this is my best guess)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just you.  This should work:

```
StorageFolder videosFolder = KnownFolders.VideosLibrary;

IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await videosFolder.GetFilesAsync();
IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> folderList = await videosFolder.GetFoldersAsync();

var count = fileList.Count + folderList.Count;
StringBuilder outputText = new StringBuilder(videosFolder.Name + " (" + count + ")\n\n");

foreach (StorageFolder folder in folderList)
{
    outputText.AppendLine("    " + folder.DisplayName + "\\");
}

foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
{
    outputText.AppendLine("    " + file.Name);
}

OutputTextBlock.Text = outputText.ToString();
```

To test for yourself, run the [Folder Enumeration Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Folder-enumeration-sample-33ebd000).  That's where the above snippet is from.

Comment: Ok, I guess this is just my computer, because the code sample you give takes 20+ seconds for me to finish, and it's hanging in the GetFilesAsync() part. I'll try the code on my RT device back home tonight, but I'm guessing it has to do with "missing" linked library folders which are not available where I am right now.

Comment: Yepp, works much, much faster at home, so the delay in listing the files at work is probably due to some missing linked video libraries/folders that are awailable here at home.